# Can someone recommend some documentation on package management for SBCL/Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

thanks in advance for the help.

Two-part question:

Part 1.

Can anyone recommend some documentation on package management for SBCL? I'm having a lot of trouble and getting surprising errors, and would love to know that I'm reading the right stuff.

Part 2.

I'd like to be able to solve my own problem, but I know that this group prefers to have reproducible issues so I'll outline what's going wrong below:

1. I wish to build a package consisting of my code, along with the :cl :postmodern and :frugal-uuid packages.
2. I use `(cl-project:make-project #P"/home/oliver/quicklisp/local-projects/hsm` to establish a system.
3. I populate the following in main.lisp in the above project folder:

```
(ql:quickload :frugal-uuid)
(ql:quickload :postmodern)

(defpackage hsm
  (:use :cl :frugal-uuid :postmodern))
(in-package :hsm)
```

Below which I define my functions.

When I evaluate `(ql:quickload :hsm)`, I get the following error:

`Package FRUGAL-UUID does not exist.`

Note that if I evaluate the above expressions from 3. in the REPL it works with no errors.

Comment: note that this is probably a typo but you wrote `:hsm-new` and not `:hsm` in `in-package`

Comment: What about https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly calling `quickload` from source files is not great:

```
(ql:quickload :frugal-uuid)
(ql:quickload :postmodern)
```

Here I suppose your `hsm.lisp` file is being compiled, and the corresponding calls to `ql:quickload` are emitted in the object file, so that when it is loaded, the code is going to be executed. But, when compiling the file, the compiler encounters `defpackage` which expands as an `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel ...)...)` which forces evaluation to happen during compilation. At this point, `:frugal-uuid` is not yet loaded because this is going to happen later, when the compiled file will be loaded.

You *could* also put calls to `ql:quickload` inside `eval-when` blocks to force the dependencies to be loaded when compiling, but the best way is to organize your code into *systems*.

Using `cl-project:make-project`, you should have an `hsm.asdf` file at the root of your project, containing something like this:

```
(defsystem "hsm"                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  :version "0.1.0"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  :author ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  :license ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  :depends-on ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  :components ((:module "src"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                :components                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                ((:file "main"))))                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  :description ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "hsm/tests"))))
```

Here you can change the dependencies of your project:

```
:depends-on (:frugal-uuid :postmodern)
```

so that when you quickload `:hsm`, it also loads its dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! That said, something seems up with the postmodern library now; for example, evaluating a function that contains ```(postmodern:query (:insert-into 'statement_maker :set 'name :null :returning 'id))``` throws an error saying that ":insert-into" is an unknown function. Oddly enough, if I load my :hsm-new package and evaluate the above expression it works just fine--it's only when evaluating a function that contains this expression that throws the error.

Comment: OK false alarm, that was a hangover from a correction I made not getting brought into the package when loaded. Follow up question, however: where can I find some good documentation to educate myself? I should note that the method I was using to build and load my package, before your help, was found by reading around.

Comment: https://gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html for packages and symbols, and https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/systems.html for systems (and transitively the ASDF manual)